# How to copy a single cell from a filtered column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy a single cell from a filtered column, the cells all have the same value (date of the document) right now the macro just copies the cell D2 specifically. I want it to copy the date corresponding to the filtered list. is there any syntax that can specify the first visible cell?

```
Sub Macro12()
'
' Macro12 Macro
'

'
Sheets("INBD").Select
Range("D2").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("J1:K2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick for you assuming that you have a header row in `D1`. It will select the first visible row after `D1` and copy it into `J1:K2`

```
Sub test()

    Sheets("INBD").Range("D2", Cells(Rows.count, "D").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 1).copy _
        Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("J1:K2")

End Sub
```

Comment: much appreciated